# logstash output to kafka - set partition key

Tags: logstash-configuration

I am new to logstash.

I am trying to read json data from files, and send it to kafka. the json i am reading contains keys for the topic, partition and the actual message.

I cant find how to set the partition key.

```
 input {
    file {
        path => "/data/files/*.*"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => "json"
    }
}
filter {
    json {
        source => message
    }
}
output {
    kafka { 
        bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
        topic_id =>  "%{topic}"
        message_key => "%{dataAsString}"
    }
}
```

Help please...

Regards, ido

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't set the partition number from Logstash. All you have is the message_key which logstash kafka producer uses to select the partition, please check the below Kafka DefaultPartitioner.scala.

```
package kafka.producer

private[kafka] class DefaultPartitioner[T] extends Partitioner[T] {
  private val random = new java.util.Random

  def partition(key: T, numPartitions: Int): Int = {
    if(key == null)
      random.nextInt(numPartitions)
    else
      key.hashCode % numPartitions
  }
}
```

As you can see if you don't give the key, then a random partition is selected. If you specify a key, then the key is hashed and moded to select between the available partitions.

To achieve what you asked for, you have to write a class like this, change logstash plugin to let you specify this class and within that plugin select the partition number.

Apache Flume lets you set the default partitioner class but I cant see a similar attirbute in logstash kafka output plugin.